# Cypress cy.wrap() after page refresh in iframe

Tags: cypress

I have the following `Cypress` test:

```
describe(`sign in`, () => {

  const getIframe = () => {

    return cy
      .get('iframe[id=my-iframe]')
      .its('0.contentDocument.body')
      .should('not.be.empty')
      .then(cy.wrap)
      .as('iFrame')
  }

  it('signs in', () => {
      
    cy.visit(PATH.SIGN_IN)
    getIframe()
    cy.get('@iFrame').find('input[name=email]').click().type('user@test.test')
    cy.get('@iFrame').find('input[name=password]').click().type('test-password')
    cy.get('@iFrame').find('button').contains(/^Sign in$/).click()
    // signin is successful and the contents of the page refresh to show a page containing <h3>Hello user</h3>
    cy.get('@iFrame').find('h3').contains('Hello user').should('be.visible')
    // the above line fails...
  })
})
```

The test fails on the last line. Even though the contents inside the iframe successfully refresh and `Hello user` is visible, Cypress is not able to find this text inside `cy.get('@iFrame')`.

How should I handle this situation correctly with Cypress?

Comment: Since it refreshes, my guess is the iframe alias references the older iframe, not newly refreshed. Have you tried using your `getIframe()` function to see if the newly refreshed iframe can be found that way?

Comment: Yeah, I tried repeating `getIframe()` right before the last line, but the result is the same...

Comment: If there is a new iframe after login, it may have a different id.

Comment: BTW `.then(cy.wrap)` isn't doing anything.

Comment: I'd recommend adding the logic as a custom command that can be called anytime you need to get the current iFrame, as opposed to a separate JS function you call once (or more) during the test. `cy.getIFrame().find...`. I'd post this as an answer but I don't have any iFrames readily available to me to test this out on.

Comment: Regarding `.then(cy.wrap)` - it is NOT not doing anything. https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/